Conditional probability of hash collision
Assume we have a infinite stream of keys. I insert each one of them into a hash table of size K. What is the probability of collision on key x given that I know a collision occurred before that at a random index in the table.

You have to share your work on it with us in order to understand what are your doubts. As it's currently posted, it seems like a task that the community has to solve for you.
